# Yves Diers's thesis ("Catégories localisables")

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, paper-request

I am looking for a copy of Yves Diers's 1977 thesis *Catégories localisables*, which is the original reference for "multi-" category theory, such as multi-adjoints, multi-colimits, and so on. Given that it is relatively widely cited (at least among those papers making use of such concepts), I was hoping a scan or digital copy exists somewhere. Does there exist a publicly available version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [Axel Osmond's suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385974), I contacted Bibliothèques MIR and they kindly scanned a copy of the thesis. They intend to make it available on Numdam. Until then, there is a PDF here:

- [Catégories localisables & Aspects geometriques de la propriete de Radon-Nikodym dans les espaces de Banach](https://github.com/CategoryTheoryArchive/archive/blob/main/resources/1977_diers_cat%C3%A9gories-localisables.pdf) (Yves Diers, 1977)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a paper version of it at the MIR7 in Paris I have currently ; maybe it is possible to ask for a numerization; this document would indeed deserve to be more accessible. Otherwise do not hesitate to contact me if I can help.

Comment: I have sent a message to enquire whether digitisation might be possible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: MIR have now scanned the thesis and plan to make it available on numdam, so hopefully it will be available publicly soon!

Comment: @varkor any news on this issue?

Comment: @UrsSchreiber: no update from the library in Paris, but since they were intending to make the thesis publicly available, I feel there is no harm in uploading it to the nLab for the time being.

Comment: @varkor Did you ever upload it to nLab? I don't see an entry in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/list+of+theses+in+category+theory

Comment: @DavidWhite: I just added it; thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [numdam](http://www.numdam.org/search/Yves%20diers-q&eprint%3DFalse/)? There is no thesis but other texts could be of interest.

Comment: There are several other of Diers's papers publicly available, which is good, but I would really like to know what is covered in the thesis; I imagine there is content in there that does not appear elsewhere.